# Could there be permission to write software on Chol Hamoed?

Tags: halacha, melacha-creative-work, chol-hamoed

Is it permissible to write computer software code on Chol Hamoed?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Unfortunately requests for decisions in personal circumstances are not a good for this site since we don't know you. It is better to turn to a rav who can ask questions regarding your specific context and deliver a personalized decision. Hope this won't deter you from coming back. Would be great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Voting to leave closed as per https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4774/, and after Chol HaMoed we can reopen this.

Comment: Hi, PLT - as an approach to an answer take a look at https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chol_HaMoed#cite_ref-34 and especially at the table "Comparison of the Reasons for which Melacha is Permitted". BUT the laws are complicated and I advise you ask your Rav.

Answer (score 2):

In the "[Chol Hamoed](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/CHOH.html)" book by R' Dovid Zucker & R' Moshe Francis, they discuss a similar question that was posed to [The Debreciner Rav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Stern) (Rav Moshe Stern).

Rav Stern (page 195-196, *teshuvah* #56) is quoted as saying:

[image]

> **Question**: Is it allowed to write something that's not necessary for Yom Tov via  a number machine (ie "a calculator" ), and this is a situation where the letters are not written on paper, but rather are illuminated by electricity on a screen and there is no writing in ink.
>
> **Answer**: **According to Torah law this is not considered writing and there is no exertion at all, and it should not be forbidden**. In regard to the prohibition of kindling a fire this is not kindling a fire at all and anyways we do not find kindling a fire unnecessarily forbidden on Chol Hamoed.

If Rav Stern is of the opinion that writing on a calculator is ok, then it's not so farfetched to suggest this could be extended to coding on a computer as well-- but should probably still [CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor) just to be safe.